# Macro imprimir varias hojas

Tags: vba

Cordial saludo

Gracias por sus aportes y ayudas...

Tengo un código para imprimir varias hojas de un archivo excel, pero ha comenzado a mostrar error...

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub CBRegistro_Click()
    Dim b As Boolean
    Dim Ruta As String
    Dim Nombre As String
    Dim paso2 As Boolean
    Nombre = UCase(InputBox("IMPRIMIR INFORME - ID DE ACCESO  -  Guardar una copia de los Registros de la Prueba ejecutada"))
    paso2 = False
    Select Case Nombre
    Case "PRIMERO"
    If UCase(InputBox("Introduce tu clave de acceso")) = "PRIMERO2020*" Then paso2 = True
    Case "CLAVEDOS"
    If UCase(InputBox("Introduce tu clave de acceso")) = "CLAVEDOS2020*" Then paso2 = True
    End Select

    If paso2 = True Then
  Const myDir As String = "C:\PRUEBAS\"
  b = True
' Aquí tengo 12 hojas para imprimir, solo muestro una…

  If ChBRegistro = True Then
    Sheets("REGISTRO").Select
    b = False
  End If
  
 '  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, myDir & TextBox1, xlQualityStandard, True, False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
' Este era mi código inicial, y lo tengo igual en varios libros y funciona perfectamente
' pero de un momento a otro comenzó a mostrar
 ' error 21470224773 (8007007b)

  Unload Me


    If Dir(myDir & nomb) <> "" Then MsgBox "El archivo ya existe, debe indicar otro nombre.": Exit Sub
 ' Este código no lo tenía antes
Ahora con este nuevo código, permite introducir la clave, pero siempre muestra el mensaje
"No existe la carpeta  (PRUEBAS)


    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, myDir &
```

TextBox1, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Exit Sub

```
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "No existe la carpeta:" & vbLf & myDir

  Sheets("INICIO").Select
  Range("B12").Select
  
  End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_MouseDown(ByVal Button As 
Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single,
```

ByVal  y As Single)
If Button = 1 Then FormX = x: FormY = y
End Sub

En varias Oportunidades me lanza este error, y resalta este último código en amarillo...

Nuevamente gracias a todos por sus aportes...

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Lo que está en esa imagen es ilegible; el código va como texto EN la pregunta. Y las mayúsculas sostenidas son innecesarias (se asimilan a gritos). Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Sí querías quitar la macro del sitio, tienes la mala suerte de olvidar que las preguntas tienen historial. Revirtiendo...